Flutter App Redirects to Blank UI after implementing user authentication feature using firebase
I'm working on a Flutter app for Android and have encountered an issue with the app's navigation behavior after implementing user authentication features using Firebase. I followed a tutorial from the WS Cube YouTube channel for integrating Firebase authentication into my app.
1- I followed the tutorial meticulously, ensuring that I integrated Firebase into my Flutter app correctly.
here are the files what i use in my project.

## pubsyml
name: firebase
description: "A new Flutter project."
publish_to: 'none'
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.2.4 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^2.27.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.17.8

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^3.0.2

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

my main dart code
import 'package:firebase/checkuser.dart';
import 'package:firebase/login.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main()async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: FirebaseOptions(apiKey: "AIzaSyDQZxWx776Vhl7Hw4VG5RhaSPX13v6ygRk",
          appId: "1:1049018787351:android:309401ce75103c0f171e52",
          messagingSenderId: "1049018787351",
          projectId: "harsh-c8ebd")
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: CheckUser(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home Screen'),
      ),
      body: Text('hello'),
    );
  }
}

login screen file in code
import 'package:firebase/helper.dart';
import 'package:firebase/main.dart';
import 'package:firebase/signuppage.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Loginpage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Loginpage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Loginpage> createState() => _LoginpageState();
}

class _LoginpageState extends State<Loginpage> {
  TextEditingController emailcontroller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordcontroller = TextEditingController();

   login(String email, String password) async {
    if (email == "" && password == "") {
      return Helper.CustomAlertBox(context, "Enter required fields");
    } else {
      try {
        UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignUpPage()),
        );
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (ex) {
        return Helper.CustomAlertBox(context, ex.code.toString());
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Login page"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Helper.CustomTextField(emailcontroller, "Email", Icons.mail, false),
          Helper.CustomTextField(
              passwordcontroller, "Password", Icons.password, true),
          SizedBox(height: 30),
          Helper.CustomButton(
                () {
              login(emailcontroller.text.toString(),
                  passwordcontroller.text.toString());
            },
            "Login",
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text("Don't have an account?"),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignUpPage()));
                },
                child: Text(
                  "Sign up",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Sign up screen code
import 'package:firebase/helper.dart';
import 'package:firebase/main.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignUpPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignUpPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SignUpPage> createState() => _SignUpPageState();
}

class _SignUpPageState extends State<SignUpPage> {
  TextEditingController emailcontroller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordcontroller = TextEditingController();

   signUp(String email, String password) async {
    if (email == "" && password == "") {
      Helper.CustomAlertBox(context, "Enter required fields");
    } else {
      try {
        UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()),
        );
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (ex) {
        return Helper.CustomAlertBox(context, ex.code.toString());
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Sign Up page"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Helper.CustomTextField(emailcontroller, "Email", Icons.mail, false),
          Helper.CustomTextField(passwordcontroller, "Password", Icons.password, true),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          Helper.CustomButton(
                () {
              signUp(emailcontroller.text.toString(), passwordcontroller.text.toString());
            },
            "Sign Up",
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

helper file code what i use as a helper in my codes.
checkuser file
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Helper {
  static  CustomTextField(TextEditingController controller, String text, IconData iconData, bool tohide) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25, vertical: 40),
      child: TextField(
        controller: controller,
        obscureText: tohide,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: text,
          suffixIcon: Icon(iconData),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  static  CustomButton(VoidCallback voidCallback, String text) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 50,
      width: 300,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: voidCallback,
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
          ),
        ),
        child: Text(
          text,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.red,
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  static Future<void> CustomAlertBox(BuildContext context, String text) {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text(text),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: Text("OK"),
            ),
          ],

        );
      },
    );
  }
}


**#CheckUser file** 
import 'package:firebase/login.dart';
import 'package:firebase/main.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CheckUser extends StatefulWidget {
  const CheckUser({super.key});

  @override
  State<CheckUser> createState() => _CheckUserState();
}

class _CheckUserState extends State<CheckUser> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return checkuser();
  }
  checkuser()async{
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if(user!=null ){
      return HomeScreen();
    }
    else {
      return Loginpage();
    }
  }


}

    



Please attach your error snapshot!

I did not find any kind of error . the UI becomes blank when i run the project.                                      Console   -                                                                                                                                      Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...
This app is linked to the debug service: ws://127.0.0.1:51047/9FGUFGtBX40=/ws
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51047/9FGUFGtBX40=/ws
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51047/9FGUFGtBX40=/ws

May be your check user file code is wrong.  because you can return only Scaffold()   page. so it's can display blank white screen.

yeah i think, that's why i update it one more . Now  i find a red screen with the error -  Expected a value of type 'Widget ', but got one of type '_Future'        See  also:https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/error.     but i am unable to solve it

please attach error snapshot properly because this link is not working!.

Of course you get a blank UI because in MaterialApp() you write CheckUser() instead of Loginpage() which is not a screen.
Change the code like this:
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Loginpage(),
    );
  }
}

Update the CheckUser file like this:
class CheckUser extends StatefulWidget {
  const CheckUser({super.key});

  @override
  State<CheckUser> createState() => _CheckUserState();
}

class _CheckUserState extends State<CheckUser> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Home();
          } else {
            return Login();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


thanks for your attention. i have just added my Checkuser file which is present just below the helper file in my given question. Now when i try to call checkuser screen the ui becomes blank?

In your ChechUser widget you have just return Scaffold() so it becomes blank because you haven't passed anything in it and also I recommend you to change your CheckUser code.

@HarshMishra I have updated my answer above, try it once.

did not work for me

i also changed my return type in checkuser file  scaffold to the function checkuser(); from youtube tutorial now i am getting a error with red screen with text  --- Expected a value of type 'Widget ', but got one of type '_Future'        See  also:https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/error.

Please move this from main.dart to a new file homepage.dart
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home Screen'),
      ),
      body: Text('hello'),
    );
  }
}


thanks for your useful suggestion . But my UI remains blank, please review my code one more time.
